# jQuery autocomplete request caching problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the [deprecated autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) (since I'm using the legacy jquery lib 1.3.2).

My problem is that the autocomplete plugin tries to cache the requests. I am using a server side url to return the results.

Consider this scenario:

```
Keyword : Results
i : ikea, iphone, ipod, ipad, iphone 4
ip: iphone, ipod, ipad, iphone4
iph: iphone, iphone 4
ipho: iphone, iphone 4
```

...

You see the problem, the first time it got 5 results - that's the limit I have set at backend, its returning 5 results only. The next time, it doesn't send a request, it refines the resultset it got in first request and so on.

How can I make the autocomplete plugin send a request everytime the input changes?

Here is my code...

```
$("#query").autocomplete(
    "/getSuggestions/", {
        autoFill: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        cacheLength: 1
    });
```

I tried setting the cacheLength to "1", but that doesn't work.

Can somebody help me out over here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#query").autocomplete(
    "/getSuggestions/", {
        autoFill: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        cacheLength: 0
    });
```

It turned out to be quite a simple solution - setting the cacheLength to 0 does the trick.

I was referring the explanation in [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) till now...

> The number of backend query results to
>   store in cache. **If set to 1** (the
>   current result), **no caching will
>   happen**. Must be >= 1.

Anyway I got the desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable caching, there is option to disable subset matching e.g.

```
$("#query").autocomplete(
    url,
    {
        matchSubset: false
    }
)
```